# Batch file which executes an exe from a specific path

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file which runs an exe from a specific path. 
Eg: I have my exe in E drive. Exact path is `E:\kk.exe`. I want to run this kk.exe from `D:\bin` folder.

I use the following command in my batch file:

```
start "D:\bin" "E:\kk.exe"
```

So far no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
start "" /d "d:\bin" "e:\kk.exe"
```

`start` command has a peculiar behaviour: the first quoted argument is the title of the window. That is the reason for the initial `""` (you can include the title you want). The rest of the line is the starting folder (`/d`, what will be the current active folder for the started process) and the command to execute.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /d "D:\bin"
start "window name" "E:\kk.exe"
```

If I've decoded your meaning correctly, you wish to run `kk.exe` while your current directory is `d:\bin`. This will create an independent process to run that program.

Note: the syntax of "start" is such that it's advisable to assign a window title (the first quoted parameter) - if you don't ant a title, leave the text out and use en empty quoted string.

However, if you just want to execute `e:\kk.exe` then

```
cd /d "D:\bin"
"E:\kk.exe"
```